# make color of headline depend on category?

Tags: categories

On my site I want the color of the category-headlines on the front page to be dependent on which category the post is. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you please share a link so I can check it and can help you.

Comment: The page is private, but I have used the Revive theme - in "full width" as a start for the page layout. See it here: https://demo.inkhive.com/revive-pro/full-width/

In the example it is the text saying "Try not to fly away", that I want to change color depending on the category.